# MS access - ranking equal values incrementally

Tags: sql, ms-access, rank

Is it possible to rank records in Access where duplicate values are given an incremental rank (like the row_number function in SQL Server)?

I want to rank the following set of records:

```
ID     Type    Score
1      Team1   4
1      Team2   2
1      Team3   1
1      Team4   1
```

The query I currently have:

```
select *
from tbl as tbl1 
where tbl1.ID in 
(  select top 3 Type
   from tbl as tbl2
   where tbl2.ID = tbl1.ID
   order by tbl2.Score )
```

Ranks them as follows

```
ID     Type    Score    Rank
1      Team1   4        1
1      Team2   2        2
1      Team3   1        3
1      Teams   1        3
```

I need to rank them like this:

```
ID    Type     Score    Rank
1      Team1   4        1
1      Team2   2        2
1      Team3   1        3
1      Team4   1        4
```

Can this be done in Access?

**Edit:**
**The rankings also need to be grouped**

Bigger sample of the data and what I want to represent in the derived column, some IDs have more records than others:

```
ID    Type     Score    Rank
1     Team1    4        1
1     Team2    2        2
1     Team3    1        3
1     Team4    1        4
2     Team1    2        1
2     Team3    2        2
2     Team2    1        3
4     Team1    4        1
4     Team3    4        2
4     Team5    3        3
4     Team4    1        4
4     Team2    1        5
```

Eventually I want to select the top 3 rows for each ID

Comment: DCount("[ID]","[mytable]","[ID]<=" & [ID]) AS row_id

Comment: Thanks, can I apply that to groups? (rank ID 1, then ID2 etc)

Comment: Do you have an example of what the groups table & query look like?

Comment: Additional details included above

Comment: For ID = 1, how do you determine whether Team 3 or Team 4 will be ranked 3rd?  They both have the same score?  Similarly, where ID = 4 how do you determine which team is 4th and which is 5th?  It's not sorted by Type, so it's not clear how the Rank is determined for teams with the same score.

Comment: I need to identify the top three values across all the Teams so for this purpose it doesn't really matter whether Team 3 or 4 are ranked higher, I just need to know that 1 is the 3rd highest value. I only want to select the top 3 values though so I need ties to be ranked incrementally, the current method ranks both Team3 and Team4 as 3 so I can't filter out the 4th value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this solution with a difference equation on two conditional aggregate count subqueries. Tiebreaker uses the order of alphabetical order `Type`:

```
SELECT tbl.ID, tbl.Type, tbl.Score,
   (SELECT Count(*) FROM tbl sub WHERE sub.ID = tbl.ID
    AND sub.Score >= tbl.Score ) 
    -
   (SELECT Count(*) - 1 FROM tbl sub WHERE sub.ID = tbl.ID
    AND sub.Type >= tbl.Type
    AND sub.Score = tbl.Score) As [Rank]

FROM tbl
ORDER BY ID, Score DESC, Type;
```

Comment: This is a pretty good solution and replicates the behavior of `RANK()` in Oracle. However, if you require a unique rank you must write a user defined function or add an additional column.